# Confusing result of Matlab's size() function

Tags: image, matlab, size

Very simple issue here I suspect, I am completely new to Matlab (1st day) and have been unable to resolve this by consulting the documentation.

As part of a larger problem, I need to get the dimensions of an image into two variables (`row_obj` and `col_obj` for the image `object`).

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/size.html):

```
[m,n] = size(obj)
```

m: The number of rows in obj.

n: The number of columns in obj.

So, following that, I wrote:

```
[row_obj, col_obj] = size(object);
    disp(row_obj);
    disp(col_obj);
    disp(size(object));
```

Which produced the output:

```
> >> call_i_spy
>     21
> 
>     81
> 
>     21    27     3
```

It appears `row_obj` is correct. If `disp(size(object))` produces `21    27     3`, then why is `col_obj` not 27 (the value I need)? What is `[row_obj, col_obj] = size(object);` actually doing?

Comment: Refer to [size](uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) from the Matlab core (not the Toolbox). Read the explanation for syntax `[d1,d2,d3,...,dn] = size(X)`. You have a 3D array and you are asking for 2 outputs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Consulting that allowed me to get the output I desired.

Comment: Since you only gave two output args, the 2nd and 3rd dimensions are being combined into one.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't just Google and click on the first thing that comes up. All of your documentation for your version of Matlab is right in the application. Type `help size` or `doc size` in your command window.